# How to change an app's name displayed in app store before submitting for review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, rename

My app's status is "prepare for submission" (way before going live), so there must be a simple way to change its name, but I really can't figure it out on my own; help's needed!
I need to change the name displayed in app store, not in xcode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change app name which is visible on `App Store` you need to change `Name` on `iTunes Connect` on your app page below the Screenshot and above app Description there is field `Name` which you need to cahnge, to change the name of app on home screen visible to user you must change `bundle display name` in your `plist`.

Comment: my situation fits the first scenario you listed, so how to do it?how to change the app name on itunesconnect?please be patient~~~